# AdMob, no aparece dinero de anuncios

Tags: google-play, admob, google-play-console

soy nuevo usar ADMob.

**Por qué *no aparece el dinero* de los anuncios (solicitudes e impresiones)? (Cabe mencionar que un día sí me apareció y ya no).**
Estoy haciendo pruebas, con varios dispositivos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Necesitas más tiempo
Las ganancias estimadas se añaden al saldo después de fin de mes. Verás el valor actualizado con las ganancias de mayo alrededor del 2 de junio.
Puedes ver esta [página](https://prestamo-amigo.com.mx/prestamos-sin-buro/) https://support.google.com/admob/answer/7356092?hl=es para más información